# Lead scoring in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm trying to assign my subscriber a lead score whenever he performs an activity like link click, mail open etc. This lead score should get updated in Salesforce against the subscriber.
My research tells me that I would require a custom ampscript to get this done. Does SFMC have a OTB functionality to support this. If I have to follow ampscript approach can someone please guide further on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather say handle this Salesforce rather than in SFMC. If you are to do the lead scoring computation in SFMC, you would need to develop a SQL query based on your send and click object. AMPSCRIPT would not work as Open or Click activity are not generated during email send. Even if you are able to compute the lead score, you cannot use OTB functionality using Marketing cloud connect for transferring the lead score back to Salesforce.

Best option is that in the Salesforce, whenever you execute a send against a lead id, a record is created in Individual Email results object and the Individual Link details object through OTB Marketing cloud connect. Individual link detail object contains the details of the link opened/ clicked by a lead. These objects are related to Lead Object using Look up relationship. You can very well write a cross object formula field or a simple apex class in Salesforce to evaluate the lead score based on Link Clicked

Comment: I'd be looking towards SalesWings rather than trying to build a custom lead scoring solution in Salesforce using formula fields and Apex. Note that SalesWings now offers native lead scoring in Marketing Cloud, where lead scores and tag attributes are populated in real-time into Data Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look as well at [www.saleswingsapp.com](https://www.saleswingsapp.com), it offers full website page visit tracking and a predictive lead scoring algorithm as-a-service. You can connect to the data through Salesforce.

It provides a list of all visited web pages, forms, and calculates automatically an interest lead score based on a proprietary algorithm to determine sales-readiness